# RPC communication between Linux and Solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, rpc

I have a RPC server running in Solaris. I have a RPC client which is running fine in Solaris.
When I compile and run the same code in Ubuntu, I am getting `Error decoding arguments` in the server.

Solaris use SunRPC (ONC RPC). Not sure how to find the version of rpc.

Is there any difference between the RPC available in Linux & Solaris?
Would there be any mismatch between the xdr generated in Solaris & Linux?

How should I find out the issue?

**Note**: Code cannot be posted

Comment: Without code, it'll be quite difficult to determine the actual problem, but one major one that comes to mind is whether you are consistently remembering to do byte-order conversions...

Comment: Solaris doesn't version ONC RPC separately from the OS, it's simply the version for that Solaris release, with whatever patches or package updates you've applied for bugfixes.

Comment: @twalberg Would there be any reason that the code works in Solaris and not in Linux? I mean the way request is sent in Linux & Solaris?

Comment: Is the Solaris platform x86 or SPARC? SPARC is big-endian and x86 is little-endian. If you aren't handling the byte order properly, then it is conceivable that you could have SPARC able to talk to SPARC and x86 to x86, but not between SPARC and x86, because the bytes in the packets would be in a different order.

Comment: @twalberg This line is taken from a SPARC to x86 Guide. `Most of the modern protocols in corporate the External Data Representation (XDR) layer, which byte swaps data if needed during transfers` RPC uses XDR and it should have been taken care right?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote any RPC/XDR code, so I don't quite know what the modern state of affairs is, but I seem to remember that there were XDR routines you needed to use to write the data into the structures/buffers that RPC used to do the communication (and on some platforms, those XDR routines simply compiled to essentially memcpy()-ish routines, while on others the did appropriate reordering. If you're filling up the RPC structures manually instead of using the XDR API to do it, you could be running into network byte order issues. Then again, I may be completely off base...

Answer (score 0):

@twalberg, @cppcoder Have you resolve the problem? I have the same problem, but I can to post my code if it will be helpfull. The some part of code is:

/* now allocate a LoopListRequestStruct and fill it with request data */

```
llrs = malloc(sizeof(LoopListRequestStruct));

fill_llrs(llrs);

/* Now, make the client request to the bossServer   */

client_call_status = clnt_call(request_client, ModifyDhctState,
        (xdrproc_t)xdr_LoopListRequestStruct,
        (caddr_t)llrs, 
        (xdrproc_t)xdr_void,
        0,
        dummy_timeval
    );
```

void fill_llrs(LoopListRequestStruct* llrs)
{

```
Descriptor_Loop* dl = 0;
DhctState_d *dhct_state_ptr = 0;
PackageAuthorization_d *pkg_auth_ptr = 0; 

llrs->TRANS_NUM = 999999;   /* strictly arbitraty, use whatever you want */
                                                    /* the bossServer simply passes this back in */
                                                    /* in the response you use it to match       */
                                                    /* request/response if you want or you can   */
                                                    /* choose to ignore it if you want           */

/* now set the response program number, this is the program number of  */
/* transient program that was set up using the svc_reg_utils.[ch]      */
/* it is that program that the response will be sent to                */

llrs->responseProgramNum = response_program_number; 

/* now allocate some memory for the data structures that will actually */
/* carry the request data */

llrs->ARG_PTR = malloc(sizeof(LoopListRequestArgs));

dl = llrs->ARG_PTR->loopList.Loop_List_val;

/* we are using a single descriptor loop at a time, this should always */
/* be the case */

llrs->ARG_PTR->loopList.Loop_List_len = 1;
llrs->ARG_PTR->loopList.Loop_List_val = malloc(sizeof(Descriptor_Loop));

/* now allocate memory and set the size for the ModifyDhctConfiguration */
/* this transaction always has 3 descriptors, the DhctMacAddr_d, the    */
/* DhctState_d, and the PackageAuthorization_d                          */

dl = llrs->ARG_PTR->loopList.Loop_List_val;
dl->Descriptor_Loop_len = 2;
dl->Descriptor_Loop_val = 
    malloc((2 * sizeof(Resource_descriptor_union)));

/* now, populate each descriptor */
/* the order doesn't really matter I'm just doing it in the order I    */
/* always have done */

/* first the mac address descriptor */

dl->Descriptor_Loop_val->type = 
    dhct_mac_addr_type;

strcpy(
    dl->Descriptor_Loop_val[0].Resource_descriptor_union_u.dhctMacAddr.dhctMacAddr,
    dhct_mac_addr
);

/* second the dhct state descriptor */

dl->Descriptor_Loop_val[1].type = 
    dhct_state_type;

dhct_state_ptr =
    &(dl->Descriptor_Loop_val[1].Resource_descriptor_union_u.dhctState);

if(dis_enable)
    dhct_state_ptr->disEnableFlag = DIS_Enabled;
else
    dhct_state_ptr->disEnableFlag = DIS_Disabled;

if(dms_enable)
    dhct_state_ptr->dmsEnableFlag = DMS_Enabled;
else
    dhct_state_ptr->dmsEnableFlag = DMS_Disabled;

if(analog_enable)
    dhct_state_ptr->analogEnableFlag = AEF_Enabled;
else
    dhct_state_ptr->analogEnableFlag = AEF_Disabled;

if(ippv_enable)
    dhct_state_ptr->ippvEnableFlag = IEF_Enabled;
else
    dhct_state_ptr->ippvEnableFlag = IEF_Disabled;

dhct_state_ptr->creditLimit = credit_limit;
dhct_state_ptr->maxIppvEvents = max_ippv_events;

/* we don't currently use the powerkey pin, instead we use an      */
/* application layer pin for purchases and blocking so always turn */   
/* pinEnable off */

dhct_state_ptr->pinEnable = PE_Disabled;
dhct_state_ptr->pin = 0;


if(fast_refresh_enable)
    dhct_state_ptr->fastRefreshFlag = FRF_Enabled;
else
    dhct_state_ptr->fastRefreshFlag = FRF_Disabled;

dhct_state_ptr->locationX = location_x;
dhct_state_ptr->locationY = location_y;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've met exactly this error during integration with the same software. Linux version really creates bad request. Reason of such behaviour is serialization of null c-string. Glibc edition of SUN rpc can't encode them, xdr_string returns zero. But the sample which you are dealing with sets 'pin' in 0. Just replace 'pin' with "", or create some wrapper over xdr_string(), and samples will work.

My patch to the PowerKey samples looks like this:

```
<       if (!xdr_string(xdrs, objp, PIN_SZ))
<               return (FALSE);
<       return (TRUE);
---
>     char *t = "";
>     return  xdr_string(xdrs, *objp? objp : &t , PIN_SZ);
```

but it can be made simpler, ofcourse. In general you should fix usage of the generated code, in my case it was 'pin' variable in the sample sources provided by software authors which must be initialized before xdr_string() call.

Comment: What 'pin' are you referring to? Where do I have to replace ""?

Comment: have you got snippet of the code shown above by Zeratul? May be we are speaking about different software. I have solved this problem while dealing with PowerKey. Anyway the problem was exactly like you described.

Answer (score 0):

Note that XDR will handle endianness but if you use app specific opaque fields, decoding will break if you don’t handle endianness yourself. Make sure integers are sent as XDR integers